# GtkTreeView: how to stop selection bar overriding background-rgba setting

Tags: gtk, gtk3

In my application the users can create a list of names associated with icons and colours. I've got the data stored in a `GtkListStore` and displayed using a `GtkTreeView`. The colour column is a `GtkCellRendererText` with the `background-rgba` property holding an opaque colour selected by the user. It looks like this.

[image: Screenshot]

However as you can see the selection bar hides the currently selected colour. The colour definition I've used in the CSS is `alpha(#cce8ff, 0.5)` and I know that the alpha is working because the colour fades out when I decrease the alpha value.

What I want is for the background colour in the cell to be visible through the selection highlight, although I could also live with the background colour blocking the selection highlight in that cell as long as the selected row was still clearly identified.

Is there some incantation I can use to achieve this? Or is this a bug in GTK3?

I'm using GTK 3.24.1 on Fedora 29. The application is written in Haskell using the gi-gtk binding.

Comment: I've had this problem too, but haven't had the time or determination to find a solution yet...

Comment: @theGtknerd I raised it as a bug on GitLab. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/1860#note_502399 The response is that the current behaviour is necessary because otherwise the interaction of program colour and theme colour could make the text unreadable.

Comment: I am sure there would be a workaround of some kind, but it is going to be according to the 'liking' of the individual programmer.

Comment: For myself, I would be satisfied with having the whole selected row the color of the colored cell. With the text in black.

Comment: @PaulJohnson Just a suggestion  but not sure if it practical. Can't you just connect the `select` signal to a c/b function in such a way that only `Item` column is highlighted and not the color? I am pretty sure this is not a bug but just an edge case for which a workaround need to found.

Comment: @sjsam Possibly, but I'd be fighting GTK3 rather than working with it, which is always a bad idea. The source code deliberately ignores the background colour when a row is selected, so I'd need separate code to draw the background in that column.